# What should be done to the snapshot directory files when migrating data to cluster version of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am migrating the tsfiles in the `sequence` and `unsequence` storage under `data/datanode/data` directories before executing `load` to the new cluster of Apache IoTDB. Please tell me if I load the entire data directory, will the files under the `snapshot` directory affect the accuracy of my data stored? Anything I need to do to deal with these files?

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore the snapshot directory after executing `flush` in Apache IoTDB. The accuracy of tsfiles will not be affected.